# touchesBegan method not called when scrolling in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I noticed touchesBegan method is not called in UIScrollView if i immediately place my finger on it and scroll.  touchesBegan only gets called after i place my finger for a certain time duration before scrolling.  Shouldn't touchesBegan always be called whenever there is a touch on the UIScrollView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that UIScrollView intercepts these events, for the purpose of figuring out if you are going to be scrolling the containing view. Actually, it looks like it gets them first (which is opposite normal processing, where the deepest subview gets them first) so that it can figure out if there is a scroll or pinch gesture. See  [How does UIScrollView steal touches from its subviews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472145/how-does-uiscrollview-steal-touches-from-its-subviews)

Comment: thx, i read that post.  do u think UIScrollView overrides its pointInside:withEvent: so that UIScrollView's touchesBegan doesn't get called?

Comment: I havent tried it, but I figured it was something like overriding - (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event to get the touch events routed to it, then do the detection, and if not detected, then do what that function used to do as a container view.

Answer (score 21):

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyBoard:)];
 [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

 -(void) hideKeyBoard:(id) sender
 {
    // Do whatever such as hiding the keyboard
 }
```

Comment: Nice, but you do not need to set the delegate.

Comment: This solution actually works pretty well for this special case.